# How to call button's onclick before textarea's onFocusOut?

Tags: javascript, html, events

So I have this td-element which contains textarea and button. When the textarea is focused the button shows and otherwise stays hidden.

The problem is when I press the button, which is supposed to remove the parent of the td-element, I lose focus of textarea and the button is hid before the button's onclick eventhandler fires.

Here are the elements:

```
<td>
    <textarea oninput='textHeight(this)' onfocus='onFocus(this)' onfocusout='onFocusOut(this)'></textarea>
    <button onclick='deleteNote(this)'>X</button>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
onFocus = (textarea) => {
    textarea.parentElement.querySelector("button").style.display = "inline";
}
onFocusOut = (textarea) => {
    textarea.parentElement.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
}
deleteNote = (btn) => {
    btn.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: you could set a small time on the onFocusOut handler

Comment: This seems to work, thank you for that, but I wonder if this is a "correct" way to do this. There could be a hiccup at the time and make it not work. It is kinda unlikely tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get your desired results. By using the `focusout` event property `relatedTarget`, we can conditionally allow the `button` to not be hidden if we click on it.

I changed your code a bit:

1. In your `textarea` inline `onfocusout` attribute, we have to pass the `window.event` property to your function so we can capture the `focusout` event.
2. We need to access the `focusout` event in your function so we include it there too:

`onFocusOut = (textarea, event) => {`

```js
onFocus = (textarea) => {
    textarea.parentElement.querySelector("button").style.display = "inline";
}
onFocusOut = (textarea, event) => {
    /* this was added to show the button if it's being clicked on*/
 if(event.relatedTarget != null){
   if(event.relatedTarget.tagName == 'BUTTON'){
   return
   }
  }
 textarea.parentElement.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
}
deleteNote = (btn) => {
    btn.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<td>
    <textarea oninput='textHeight(this)' onfocus='onFocus(this)' onfocusout='onFocusOut(this, window.event)'></textarea>
    <button onclick='deleteNote(this)'>X</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Works just like I wanted to. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

what if you don't hide the button when textarea is not empty?

```
onFocusOut = (textarea) => {
    if (textarea.value === "")
        textarea.parentElement.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I am making a little note app and I think it looks ugly when there are 10 notes and everyone has the delete button. It also reduces the risk of deleting a note accidentally when scrolling trough them.